# views 3, show exposed filter - User: name, as list instead of autocomplete text field

Tags: 7, views

Drupal 7 Views 3, Is this possible and how

The default exposed filter form for filtering by user name shows up as a textfield in which the user types the username by which to filter and a nice autocomplete

I want this to be a jump menu or list with check boxes instead so the user can see al the names listed and choose from that list (like the taxonomy list)

Comment: The reason for this is that users would typically be many. Having prepopulated elements like you suggest doesn't scale past 20 or so. Taxonomy lists could cause huge problems for this very reason.

Comment: that's true, but it would be useful to be able to either limit by role or provide a view result set